# Distance between plane and elliptic paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis

> Find a point on the plane $z = x + y - 2$ and a point on the surface $z = x^2 + y^2$ such that the distance between them is minimized.

I know what is happening. But I just don't know where to start. I am self-teaching vector calculus. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: Find the point on the surface where the normal vector is parallel to the normal vector of the plane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark! I have realized that the normal for the tangent plane and the normal for the plane should be equal (not only parallel)...otherwise, the whole point of finding the shortest distance would be contradicted. But thanks for the hint, I couldn't believe how easy this question is! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the extension of Lagrange method to find minimum of function $$f(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2) = (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 - z_1)^2$$ express the distance of two point $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2,z_2)$
subject to 2 constrain are

$$g_1(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2) = x_1 + y_1 -2 = 0$$  and  $$g_2(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2) = x_2^2 + y_2^2 - z_2 = 0$$
[Lagrange extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUpj2.png)

Comment: [$\LaTeX$ tips](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): you can use `$`s around your maths to use $\LaTeX$ almost like normal. (In fact you'll be using MathJax, but still similar)

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of the paraboloid is

$ g = (2 x, 2 y , -1) $

And the normal to the plane is

$ n = (1, 1, -1) $

And we want to have

$ g = k n $

for $k \ne 0 $.

Thus

$ 2 x = k$

$ 2 y = k $

$ -1 = - k $

Hence,  $ k = 1 $ and $ x = y = \dfrac{1}{2} $ , i.e. the point of the paraboloid closest to the plane is $ R =  ( \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2} ) $

The projection of $R$ onto the plane is

$ Q = R_0 + P (R - R_0) $

where $R_0$ is a point on the plane, for example, $ R_0 = (0,0,-2) $

and

$ P = I - \dfrac{ n n^T }{ n^T n } = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} - \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && - 1 \\ 1 && 1 && -1 \\ -1 && -1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && -1 && 1 \\ -1 && 2 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore,

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} + \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && -1 && 1 \\ -1 && 2 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{5}{2} \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} + \dfrac{1}{6} \begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 6 \\ 12 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, $Q= (1, 1, 0) $ is the point on the plane that is closest to the paraboloid.